# How to convert number to date string

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have df where the date field is like 20190719000823917

I would like to convert it to 19-07-2019 00:08:23:917

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')`?

Comment: @piRSquared are you sure? Runs fine on pandas `0.24.2`.

Comment: Hmm... checking my version.  did you import it as string?  Or are they integers?  I have `0.24.2`... Well I'll be...  it works, I didn't even bother to check.  Must have been some prior version in which it didn't, at least I hope, so I can save face (-:

Comment: I have used:
df["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
Some values are 2019072023492677.0 
and 2.0190723031232268e+16

Comment: @piRSquared: I think you can save face, because the docs of 0.19 specifies `arg : string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series`. Unless the docs is wrong, version 0.19.x doesn't allow `int/float` :)